# Httppost mysql is empty

Tags: php, android, mysql, http-post

I have searched for awhile but have not found a solution to this yet. I am sending an httppost to my php file which then stores it in my mysql database. But when i check the database i see empty post. I see it inserted the entry but the values are empty. I have checked my php code and if i manually ping the url with the information it puts it into the database. My logcat shows no errors.

```
public class Add extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private Button add_btn;
EditText name;
EditText addy;
EditText hours;
EditText desc;
TextView error;
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
InputStream is;

  @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.add);

      add_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add_btn);
      add_btn.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);

      name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.action_name);
      addy = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.action_addy);
      hours = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.action_hours);
      desc = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.action_desc);
      error = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.error_text);
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mapnav, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onClick(View v)
{ 
    if(v == add_btn)
    {
        if(name.getText().length()== 0)
        {
            error.setText("You Must enter a bussiness name.");
        }
        else if(desc.getText().length()== 0)
        {
            error.setText("Please enter a short description. I.E. Beer Bar or Dance Club");
        }
        else
        {
            new Connect().execute();

            name.setText("");
            addy.setText("");
            hours.setText("");
            desc.setText("");
        } 
    }
}

private class Connect extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 
{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        super.onPreExecute();    
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {           
        try
        {
            String a = name.getText().toString().trim();
            String b = addy.getText().toString().trim();
            String c = hours.getText().toString().trim();
            String d = desc.getText().toString().trim();

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new
                    HttpPost("http://www.website.com/phpfile.php");

            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bname", a));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("baddy", b));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bhours", c));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bdesc", d));

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,HTTP.UTF_16));

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
            Log.e("Server Response: ", " " + response);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
            //error.setText("Connection error");
        }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your server expects the post body parameters encoded as UTF_16?  Typically, it's UTF_8 I believe, may or may not be the issue. EDIT: Think I've spotted the issue, check below for posted answer.

Comment: Excellent.. That was the solution. Thanks so much, i been searching for hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As posted in the comments, the post body should have been encoded as UTF_8.

Comment: Ryan it was your first thing about the utf 8. Edit your answer to that and I will accept it. Thanks again.